# What is PropSet in crawled property?

Tags: 2013, search

I'm working with SP2013 Search and I need to create crawled properties by PowerShell script. I found out that I can use New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty function, but I have not found what is `-PropSet` property.

```
$crPropery = New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -SearchApplication $searchApp -Category  $searchCategory -PropSet $propSetId -Name $crPropertyName -VariantType $variantType -IsNameEnum $false
```

I know that SharePoint Search by default uses these PropSetIds:

- 158d7563-aeff-4dbf-bf16-4a1445f0366c - TaxonomyField
- fea84df6-a0fc-492c-9aa7-d28b8dcb08b3 - SPFieldMultiLineText, HtmlField, ImageField, LinkField
- ed280121-b677-4e2a-8fbc-0d9e2325b0a2 - SPFieldText, SPFieldChoice, SPFieldMultiChoice, SPFieldNumber, SPFieldCurrency, SPFieldDateTime, SPFieldBoolean, SPFieldUser, SPFieldUrl, SPFieldGuid
- 00130329-0000-0130-c000-000000131346 - other field types

What is `PropSet`? What actions SharePoint does depend on it? Should I use `PropSet` depends on field type?

In additional, by default SharePoint creates two crawled property for some field types, for example, if you have field "sp test" of SPFieldText type, Sharepoint creates

1. sptestOWSTEXT - management property
2. ows_q_TEXT_sptest - crawled property which is mapped to sptestOWSTEXT, has ed280121-b677-4e2a-8fbc-0d9e2325b0a2 propSetId and unchecked Include in full-text index
3. ows_sp_x0020_test - crawled property which is not mapped to any management property, has 00130329-0000-0130-c000-000000131346 propSetId and checked Include in full-text index

Could you explain for what purpose SharePoint creates ows_sp_x0020_test crawled property?

Comment: Sorry can't help but your question helped explain something for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on crawled property the crawler creates additional crawled properties.

For example if you create a publishing HTML field, the 'normal' crawled property only contains the text that is in the HTML field (without the HTML markup).

The crawler creates additional crawled properties to be able to get to the complete HTML. The property with a `ows_r_HTML_` prefix will include the HTML, but only if you specify the correct `SourceId` in your field definition.

More info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9ea5648f-e8af-4deb-9e1a-99af07c3142d/publishing-html-field-and-crawled-properties?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 8):

In SharePoint 2013 is **PropSet** related to **SPFieldType**. If you create your property with GUID 00130329-0000-0130-c000-000000131346 SharePoint will create new property with same name and correct GUID.

**158d7563-aeff-4dbf-bf16-4a1445f0366c** - TaxonomyField

**fea84df6-a0fc-492c-9aa7-d28b8dcb08b3** - SPFieldMultiLineText, HtmlField, ImageField, LinkField

**ed280121-b677-4e2a-8fbc-0d9e2325b0a2** - SPFieldText, SPFieldChoice, SPFieldMultiChoice, SPFieldNumber, SPFieldCurrency, SPFieldDateTime, SPFieldBoolean, SPFieldUser, SPFieldUrl, SPFieldGuid

**00130329-0000-0130-c000-000000131346** - other field types

Here you have correct crawled property names https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136.aspx

Here is PowerShell script for creating Crawled Properties:

```
function EnsureCrawledProperty([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField]$f, $sa)
{
    $CrawlPropName = ""
    $CrawlPropSet = ""
    $PropSetTax = "158d7563-aeff-4dbf-bf16-4a1445f0366c" # - TaxonomyField
    $PropSetMulti = "fea84df6-a0fc-492c-9aa7-d28b8dcb08b3" # - SPFieldMultiLineText, HtmlField, ImageField, LinkField
    $PropSetSingle = "ed280121-b677-4e2a-8fbc-0d9e2325b0a2" # - SPFieldText, SPFieldChoice, SPFieldMultiChoice, SPFieldNumber, SPFieldCurrency, SPFieldDateTime, SPFieldBoolean, SPFieldUser, SPFieldUrl, SPFieldGuid
    $PropSetOther = "00130329-0000-0130-c000-000000131346" # - other field types

    Switch ($f.Type)
    {
        # propset multi
        $([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Note)         { $CrawlPropName = "ows_r_MTXT_$($f.InternalName)"; $CrawlPropSet = $PropSetMulti }
        # propset single
        $([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text)         { $CrawlPropName = "ows_q_TEXT_$($f.InternalName)"; $CrawlPropSet = $PropSetSingle }
        $([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Choice)       { $CrawlPropName = "ows_q_CHCS_$($f.InternalName)"; $CrawlPropSet = $PropSetSingle }
        $([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::MultiChoice)  { $CrawlPropName = "ows_q_CHCM_$($f.InternalName)"; $CrawlPropSet = $PropSetSingle }
        $([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Number)       { $CrawlPropName = "ows_q_NMBR_$($f.InternalName)"; $CrawlPropSet = $PropSetSingle }
        $([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Currency)     { $CrawlPropName = "ows_q_CURR_$($f.InternalName)"; $CrawlPropSet = $PropSetSingle }
        $([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::DateTime)     { $CrawlPropName = "ows_q_DATE_$($f.InternalName)"; $CrawlPropSet = $PropSetSingle }
        $([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Boolean)      { $CrawlPropName = "ows_q_BOOL_$($f.InternalName)"; $CrawlPropSet = $PropSetSingle }
        $([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::User)         { $CrawlPropName = "ows_q_USER_$($f.InternalName)"; $CrawlPropSet = $PropSetSingle }
        $([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::URL)          { $CrawlPropName = "ows_q_URLH_$($f.InternalName)"; $CrawlPropSet = $PropSetSingle }

        default {

            if($f -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField])
            {
                $CrawlPropName = "ows_taxId_$($f.InternalName)"; $CrawlPropSet =  $PropSetTax
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Warning "Unknown type $($f.Type)"
            }

        }

    }

    $existingProp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -Name $CrawlPropName -SearchApplication $sa

    if($existingProp -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Output "Creating crawled property $CrawlPropName for $($f.InternalName)"
        New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -Category SharePoint -IsNameEnum $false -Name $CrawlPropName -PropSet $CrawlPropSet -SearchApplication $sa -VariantType 0 | Out-Null
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "Crawled property $CrawlPropName for $($f.InternalName) already exists"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The PropSet of a crawled property isn't related to the **field type** but to the **category**.

When you look at the crawled properties in the UI you'll see that they are grouped in **categories** like *SharePoint*, *Business Data*, *Web*, *Office*, etc. These **categories** represent the source "type" of the crawled property.

For instance, when you define a custom field in a list, like your field "sp test", SharePoint will automatically pick this field up when it's crawling your content and it will turn it into a crawled property in the *SharePoint* **category**. Would you be crawling an external, non SharePoint, website, SharePoint will automatically create crawled properties for all the -tags in the crawled HTML and those crawled properties will show up in the *Web* **category**. This goes for other **categories** too: *Business Data* shows crawled properties retrieved from BCS-sources, *Office* shows crawled properties retrieved from Office document properties like the title or author of a document. The **PropSet** is merely the (GU)ID of the **Category**.

The ows_sp_x0020_test crawled property in your question is what I stated before: a "regular" crawled property that SharePoint picks up when crawling your SharePoint content. It puts the property in category *SharePoint* which has PropSet *00130329-0000-0130-c000-000000131346*. I'm not entirely sure why the ows_q_TEXT_sptest property gets created though, but I guess that's a SharePoint 2013 specific thing...

~Mark

Comment: It is 2010 specific thing...